# Python model for "Exploiting earnings volatility by Brian Johnson"

Tags: volatility

Brian Johnson has written great book on Exploiting Earnings Volatility. He explains how to use his novel approach to 1) solve for the expected level of earnings volatility implicitly priced in an option matrix, 2) calculate historical levels of realized and implied earnings volatility, 3) develop strategies to exploit divergences between the two, and 4) calculate expected future levels of implied volatility before and after earnings announcements and develop trade to gain volatility to your advantage.

He has provided 2 excel sheets. Excel solver has few limitation, may not always come to optimal solution. I was wondering if anyone has converted this to Python ? Any pointers ?

Thanks

Comment: Where are there excel sheets available?

Comment: @DavidDuarte: It is hidden in the last section Spreadsheet Tools of the appendix. If you find the description of the option model the author uses please let me know.

Comment: What option model is he using? Is there a description? Can you see the code? Otherwise, how would you convert the solver to Python?

Comment: Unless there are details you're not sharing (eg, local v. global minima) it's highly likely that any optimization routine in Python would arrive at the same suboptimal solution.  The issue is likely more a weakness of optimization not Excel.

Comment: @Hans Thank for your reply. Author uses his own formulae (I assume they are slighlty modifed from Black Scholes model but pretty similar). 
He has 2 youtube video where he explain his model 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esDRVtnZz08&ab_channel=TraderEdge
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08vWKmNhXN8&ab_channel=TraderEdge

I have file with VBA code. Can I upload it here ? I didn't see option to upload

Comment: @Chris : please see above 2 videos if you want to get more details.

Comment: Yes, the book just uses the Black-Scholes formula. It just assumes the total variance is simply the sum of the variance from a constant volatility for every non-earnings-annoucement days and a special variance for the earnings-announcement day. You just need to fit this model to the ATM options prices on the same stock over a slew of expirations. It is pretty easy to code.